# Application of a Formula on MySql Table Column after Counting the Occurrences of Items inside the Column.

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which looks like:

```
brand satisfaction
    A   offered
    N   good
    L   bad
    A   good
    N   good
    L   good
    A   bad
    N   bad
    L   offered
    A   offered
    N   bad
    L   bad
    N   bad
    L   bad
```

By applying :

```
SELECT  brand,satisfaction, COUNT(satisfaction) as Number
FROM
table
WHERE satisfaction LIKE 'good' OR satisfaction LIKE 'bad' OR satisfaction LIKE 'offered'
GROUP BY brand, satisfaction
```

gave me a new table (table2) which looks like:

```
brand satisfaction Number
A   offered        2
A   good           1
A   bad            1
N   offered        0
N   good           2
N   bad            3
L   offered        1
L   good           1
L   bad            3
```

I want to apply a formula `((good-bad)/good+bad+offered)` grouped by brand to get result table (table3) like this:

```
brand afterformula
A     0
N    -0.2
L    -0.5
```

What have I tried so far?. I have been able to solve the problem but only by first saving the table2 in database and applying the following query:

```
SELECT brand, (MAX(CASE WHEN satisfaction = 'good' THEN Number  ELSE 0 end )-MAX(CASE WHEN satisfaction = 'bad' THEN Number  ELSE 0 end ))
/ (MAX(CASE WHEN satisfaction = 'bad' THEN Number  ELSE 0 end )+  MAX(CASE WHEN satisfaction = 'good' THEN Number  ELSE 0 end )+ MAX(CASE WHEN satisfaction = 'offered' THEN  Number ELSE 0 end )) AS
'afterformula' 
FROM  table2  
group by brand
```

The problem is that I need to apply the formula to the first table itself for the automation job that I need it for and the original table is huge with about 5 million rows. Could anyone please help me or give me tips, how could I achieve the result. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to calculate each value in a single row:

```
SELECT brand,
       SUM(satisfaction = 'good') as good,
       SUM(satisfaction = 'bad') as  bad,
       SUM(satisfaction = 'offered') as offered
FROM table
WHERE satisfaction LIKE 'good' OR satisfaction LIKE 'bad' OR satisfaction LIKE 'offered'
GROUP BY brand;
```

Then you can use a subquery (or complicated formula in the above):

```
SELECT b.*,
       (good - bad) / (good + bad + offered) as formula
FROM (SELECT brand,
             SUM(satisfaction = 'good') as good,
             SUM(satisfaction = 'bad') as  bad,
             SUM(satisfaction = 'offered') as offered
      FROM table
      WHERE satisfaction LIKE 'good' OR satisfaction LIKE 'bad' OR satisfaction LIKE 'offered'
      GROUP BY brand
     ) b;
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm :)